# Open sharepoint site in google crome on dev box

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, error

I am trying to browse sharepoint site on dev site on the google crome but getting this below error. The site works fine with IE

[image]

**Update the image**  : Right Click on Chrome shortcut >> Properties >> Then Append --explicitly-allowed-ports=77 to shortcut target - I am getting the below error

[image]

Comment: I have the same error and below solution is not working for me. I can open my central admin in chrome but not web application.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the issue here is that Chrome does not, by default, allow traffic through all ports. Notice in the screenshot that it's returning Error 312 (UNSAFE_PORT)... it would seem that port 77 is an unsafe port.

From Superuser.com:

> Right Click on Chrome shortcut >> Properties >>
>   Then Append --explicitly-allowed-ports=xxx to shortcut target

https://superuser.com/questions/188006/how-to-fix-err-unsafe-port-error-on-chrome-when-browsing-to-unsafe-ports

Comment: Hi Ted, I tried it but i am getting an error - i have updated the question with the error screen shot

Comment: Hm... make sure you specified --explicitly-allowed-ports=xxx in the shortcut and not just explicitly-allowed-ports - the '--' is important.

Comment: Hi Ted, i have used the --explicitly-allowed-ports=xxx, but still having no luck - i have updated the screenshot

Comment: Ah, just tried this out myself...if you have any quotes within your Target box (""), remove them and try again. That fixed it for me.

Comment: Hi Ted .. Thanks for the solution ..it worked "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --explicitly-allowed-ports=77

Answer (score 0):

Chrome does not pass credentials by default like IE does so this would actually be normal and expected behavior if: 1) the site allows anonymous access and 2) the site uses a master page, page layout or page other server-side referenced file that has no published version.

The solution is to make sure that everything that goes into rendering the desired page is checked in and published.  This also includes any javascript or images that might be referenced on the server-side.

Answer (score 0):

This worked perfectly after a few attempts.

To be clear, you paste `--explicitly-allowed-ports=xxx` after the quotation marks in the target e.g.:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --explicitly-allowed-ports=79
```

I could then access the local site on the port I specified and it got round the ERR_UNSAFE_PORT issue.